# Unable to make character controller jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue where firstly controller.isGrounded returns false when the character is moving even though it is still grounded, and secondly my jump does nothing.

I'm also not sure why everyone online recommends character controllers as they have only been unnecessarily difficult to work with, especially compared to rigid bodies.

Here's my code:

```
    public Transform cam;
    public float speed = 6f, turnSmoothTime = 0.1f, jumpSpeed = 10f;
    float turnSmoothVelocity;
    Vector3 moveDir;
    bool moved = false;

    void Update()
    {
        

        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

        if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);

            moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
            
            controller.Move(moveDir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            moved = true;
        }

        if (!controller.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDir += Physics.gravity;
            controller.Move(moveDir * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log("Fall");
            moved = true;
        }

        if (controller.isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            moveDir.y = jumpSpeed;
            Debug.Log("Jump");
            controller.Move(moveDir * Time.deltaTime);
            moved = true;
        }


        if(!moved)
        {
            moveDir = Vector3.zero;
        }
        moved = false;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1st question: The isGrounded returns true only when it is stationary, if you want to check if the character is touching the ground maybe use collision methods or sth. else.

2nd question: The way you are trying to make the character jump isn't optimal at all, it may be failing because how clunky it is. Try using the AddForce method.

Comment: The whole point of using this character controller I thought is that it has these built in functions. AddForce is a rigidbody method.